# How can I determine what does my mobile application require?

Tags: c#, java, android, windows-phone-7, mobile

I'm confused between native apps and web apps in the mobile context. I don't know if I go with native mobile development then do I need to know HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. If not then how can I make that app connect to database online for example?

If I want to build an application for chatting on mobiles. Something like WhatsApp! Will knowing a programming language (e.g. Java on Android and C# on Windows Phone) will be enough to build something like that? or what other components are necessary to add?

Comment: You need to learn about networking and HTTP, which has nothing to do with HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Native apps tend to be more recommended for android apps as they are faster as it is running what it was intended i.e. java code, html web apps tend to be slower.

For what you want to do, a chat app, then a native android app, (using java code) will probably work best then trying to do it as a web app.

You would need to learn about Http connections for your chat application. If you are accessing a database, such as MySQL, then you would need to have PHP code running on a web service where the Android app can access the database.

As an example, if your application, need to query the database, then you would tell the Android app to post to the web server running the PHP code. The PHP code would run the query on the MySQL database, and the result set should be json encoded and echo'd out, that way, Android will receive the json encoded content. Then you would need to decode the json to process what was returned in some way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That helps but why including PHP, will Java not be able to to access databases?

Comment: No, there is no Java library that is compatible with android to connect to databases such as MySQL. That's why you need to have PHP running on a server that android can talk to and the PHP does the MySQL handling for you

Answer (score 0):

For android you will need to learn Java and XML, and if you want to make a chatting application for all or either platforms you must learn SQL, (including php).

Comment: So to mix Java and PHP after that? did you mean this?